# How to make Jira trigger plugin to work in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jira

I'm configuring Jira trigger plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin) in Jenkins:

[JIRA Trigger Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg0b5.png)

We use Jira DC version and already set the webhook up as described in the documentation shared by @ceilfors. The Jenkins job is very simple:

[Jenkins Build Triggers configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHNip.png)

Also configured a Logger to triage any isue:

[Configure log recorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjCvy.png)

So when I add a comment on a task under project SNDBX I can see Jira is firing the webhook created:

[Jira firing the webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpQf3.png)

However in Jenkins nothing happens, I checked "All Jenkins Logs" and I get:

[Jenkins logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byZMp.png)

And the logger for jira webhook is showing:

[Jira Webhook logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQd8r.png)

So the we webhook is "reaching" Jenkins somehow.

BTW, I have Jenkins over Java 8 installed:

[Jenkins configuration xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CixPh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fixed. It was an issue on my Jira server not trusting (SSL cert) Jenkins srvr.